# Can you provide me with the source code of DMRG writen by C++?

Tags: c++, computational-physics

I want to study the Density matrix renormalization Group(DMRG). Can some one provide me with the souce code which is writen by **C++** for study purpose only? The code is not necessiary very professional, but works.

Comment: There are some links here to different DMRG implementations, including C++:

http://www.itp.uni-hannover.de/~jeckelm/dmrg/

Comment: Yes, thanks. I once visted the website as suggested by you. However, I prefer some algorithms which don't depend any special library.

Comment: The BLOCK code of Chan and coworkers is online somewhere AFAIK.

Comment: ALPS has a C++ DMRG code for lattice models written by Feigun.

Comment: @Roger209 Libraries are a best practice in software. You should avoid any implementation that _doesn't_ use them.

Comment: @Jeff: Thank you very much for your hints. Actually, I have made my own program of the DMRG. For example, for the calculation of the ground state energy of spin-1/2 Heisenberg model, Only 40s are needed for the length $L=100$ with $m=100$ states kept.